# Selection of unique objects where the attribute is a list of other objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class

```
public class Address
{
    public List<AddressElement>? address;
    public int weight;
    public int missingComponents;
}
```

And I have a list of objects of a given class

```
List<Address> addresses = new();
```

My task is to ensure that the addresses contain objects with unique List<AddressElement>? address.
How can this be done most effectively?

Below is a small fragment of the AddressElement class

```
public class AddressElement
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public uint ObjectId { get; set; }
    public Guid ObjectGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte Level { get; set; }
    public string UpdateDate { get; set; }
    ...
    public bool IsActual { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is a unique List<AddressElement> at all? When is it a duplicate, if it contains the same number of AddressElements, in the same order and with the same properties? What if the order is different or there are duplicates but one list has more items than the other?

Comment: _"My task is to ensure that the addresses contain objects with unique List<AddressElement>?"_ - and what is the definition of the uniqueness in this case? Please share some sample data and desired outputs. Also is this in-memory or actually a query via some ORM?

Comment: In my case, uniqueness is when two objects have the same property values. Quantity, order, etc. not important. The list of addresses is generated from the file.

Comment: addresses = addresses.DistinctBy(a => a.address, new SequenceEqualityComparer<AddressElement>()).ToList(); gives the error Compiler error CS0121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to make `AddressElement` a record, which has a built-in equality comparer and to use a custom `SequenceEqualityComparer` for the list comparison:

```
class SequenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T>? a, IEnumerable<T>? b)
    {
        if (a == null) return b == null;
        if (b == null) return false;
        return a.SequenceEqual(b);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> val)
    {
        return val.Where(v => v != null)
            .Aggregate(0, (h, v) => h ^ v!.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

---

```
public record AddressElement
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public uint ObjectId { get; set; }
    public Guid ObjectGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte Level { get; set; }
    public string UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActual { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

---

Then the code to remove duplicates is:

```
addresses = addresses.DistinctBy(a => a.address, new SequenceEqualityComparer<AddressElement>()).ToList();
```

You could also use `GroupBy`, to control which addresses should remain:

```
addresses = addresses.GroupBy(a => a.address, new SequenceEqualityComparer<AddressElement>())
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(a => a.weight).First())
    .ToList();
```